# How do I set the target frame for form submission in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, forms, postback, target

I have an asp.net page in an iframe where all links target _blank

```
<base target="_blank" />
```

But I want the form on it to submit to _self (i.e. the iframe where the page is located) when the one button is clicked. The form is an `<asp:Panel>` with an `<asp:Button>` control for submitting it.

Where can I set the target for this form? Since there isn't a `<form>` tag or an `<input>` tag in the file (ASP.NET makes them when it renders the page), I don't know how to change the target to override my `<base>` tag.

Comment: Do you mean you want to submit to the page that contains the iFrame?

Comment: I want the submission to target the iframe the page is in, as it would if I didn't have the <base> tag in there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found [this post](http://forums.asp.net/p/1022866/1387357.aspx) on the asp.net forums by [mokeefe](http://forums.asp.net/members/mokeefe.aspx) that changes the target by javascript.

I just put it in my page and tried it. I had to make these modifications:

**1.** I'm using asp tags only, so I have `<asp:Button>` not `<input type="button">` and my **onclick** has to be the server-side method I'm calling on submission. Therefore I put this new javascript in **OnClientClick**:

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdEmailSearch" runat="server" Text="Search"
            OnClick="cmdEmailSearch_Click"
            OnClientClick="javascript:pageSubmit()"/>
```

**2.** I removed the myForm.submit() since ASP.NET renders the page putting the **WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions()** javascript in the button's **onclick** right after it puts my **pageSubmit()**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageSubmit(){
        // where form1 is the Parent Form Id
        var myForm = document.getElementById('form1');
        myForm.target = '_self';
    }// end function
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I understood you right, but you can set the target in the form tag, like this:

```
<form method=post action="Page.aspx" target="_self">
```

Comment: the trick is I'm using the ASP.NET one-form-per-page thing. My "form" is an asp:Panel tag, so I can't put the target attribute anywhere (I need my <base target="_blank"> so my links on the page go to a new tab)