# LinkButton or HyperLink?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a situation where I'm not sure if I should use a HyperLink or LinkButton. When a user clicks on a list of links I want to trigger a click event where I save some information to session (should use LinkButton) but I also want these links to open up new tabs (should use HyperLink).

Comment: You can POST the form to a different window: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274566/how-do-i-set-the-target-frame-for-form-submission-in-asp-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say a HyperLink that hits a specific URL to store the necessary session data, then use `Response.Redirect` to redirect to the following page after storing the information.

The HyperLink's URL would point to your server so that you can store the information, and then you would use a redirect to point the user to the correct endpoint after storing the necessary data.

**Example**

1. HyperLink's URL points to `~/yourpage.aspx?state=NY`, with `target="_blank"`
2. Server responds to URL and checks querystring.
3. If query string exists, store data (`if (Request.QueryString["state"] != null) Session["state"] = Request.QueryString["state"]`)
4. Redirect the user to the appropriate URL (`Response.Redirect("http://www.ny.gov")`)

If the data is at all confidential, then you would want to use the `LinkButton` methods pointed out in other answers. Opening up a new tab is tricky, so you would probably have to write out some Javascript as outlined in @andleer's answer since I don't believe there is an easy way to pop open a new window from the server side otherwise.

Comment: To the OP: how does this open new tabs? Also by linking off a client side HyperLink / `<a>` tag, you lose all of your server side state. This is a perfectly acceptable design architecture, but it kind of defeats the  purpose of web forms on asp.net. A fine answer but I don't see how it addresses your question...

Comment: @andleer HyperLink has `target="_blank"` which will open the new tab. The `NavigateUrl` points to your server and uses query string parameters. Your session cookie will be included in the request, so you can put the parameters in Session, and then `Response.Redirect()` in the new tab. This means you don't have to do *any* Javascript to cause the new window. The key component is that the `HyperLink` hits your server *first* before redirecting

Answer (score 3):

A `LinkButton` will `postback`, it's essentially a button that renders like a link.  You could set a `response.redirect(url)` in the event handler to set a new tab.

Can you add more information, of what you want to do in the handler, maybe this could be achieved with `Jquery` calling a server-side method?

[Difference between Hyperlink and LinkButton](http://dotnetbutchering.blogspot.co.uk/2008/02/aspnet-difference-between-hyperlink-and.html)

[`Click Api with Jquery`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [`Jquery post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: I think I'm going to have to use js to save the info (state abbreviation). Do you know of a way to open a new tab with Response.Redirect?

Comment: which tabs are you using? You may only need to set a tab index in the event, or possibly a hash, like `#tab1` ?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use a `LinkButton` which causes a PostBack. To open additional tabs, emit JavaScript.

```
protected void MyLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["MyData"] = 123;

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(),
            "newWindow",
            "window.open('http://myurl','_blank');",
            true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LinkButton`.

The difference between the two is that `LinkButton` postbacks your page to the server allowing you to make your logic while `HyperLink` does not postbacks - just redirects you to the specified link, therefore, use `HyperLink` when you want to navigate.

Comment: actually, hyperlink can postback depending on the runat attribute in your control and if you handle a click event

Comment: I thought hyperlinks don't have OnClick handlers

Comment: ah yes hyperlinks do not have a on click

Answer (score 1):

The LinkButton control is used to create a hyperlink button. This control looks like a HyperLink control but has the same functionality as the Button control.
with LinkButton you also get the facility of Web Control Standard Properties and Control Standard Properties .

Answer (score 0):

You're right, can't do both, since a LinkButton will trigger a postback, and a hyperlink will simply navigate to a new page.

In your case use you can use a LinkButton and the server code will have to to do a redirect (if you want to navigate to another page) or handle the Tabs and return the page with the Tab opened if you are using a tabs element. (so the tab navigation will not be done front end)

Answer (score -1):

In such cases you can use button for saving some information and you can also use it as a like option. But if you want to add a link then you have to use hyperlink.. You can also use javascript to link a url with the button so that when user clicks on that button the session information will get stored and then he will redirected to the new webpage.